# Is it safe to make a database connection using appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to make a project in blazor wasm and make it public, but is it safe to connect to MySql using `appsettings.json`?

In other words, is `appsettings.json` from a Blazor project automatically picked up and shipped to end-user's browser, thus exposing configuration data?

Comment: Hello!
Did you do some research on it? What have you found? What is your opinion on this and what difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: Blazor WASM can't connect to databases, only the backend Web API can. In which case all the techniques used to secure connection strings are available. If you use Windows authentication (which *is* available in MySQL with some fiddling) you won't need to store credentials in the connection string

Comment: How is the API service deployed? And what are you trying to defend against? If only the service account/app pool account can access the `appsettings.json` file, it's pretty secure. Make sure the production credentials don't end up in version control though. This would fail if API allows arbitrary code execution, eg with `Process.Start`, which could allow someone to execute `type appsettings.json` or something similar. Configuration can read from multiple sources, including environment variables, Keyvault, other JSON files etc.

Comment: This is a good question. Me, having zillion years of experience with web development, .NET, SPAs, etc..., but not Blazor, I have no clue what parts of C# logic or configuration can end up being shipped to the client. Clearly, it's common sense that DB connection data will not, since client can't even connect to DB directly, but it would be cool if someone tells us clearly what "the logic" of blazor is.

Comment: @Nenad this is not a good question because the WASM appsettings.json has nothing to do with databases. What gets shipped is pretty clear - what's in the client project. What happens is documented in the Blazor docs in the Getting Started section, the Tutorials, and the articles, blog posts and courses on Blazor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you answer my "clarification" question please, I appended to the original? Here in the comment? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It's not safe.

Blazor web assembly is a client application which will run at the client's browser, so all the information could be found at client.

Besides, by default we will not use appsettings.json in the Blazor web assembly application.

The right way should be you should create a web api which connect to your SQL server instead of directly connecting inside the web assembly.

Comment: It's not safe only if you have to store the credentials in the connection string.

Comment: More to the point, I suspect the OP uses `appsettings.json` to refer to the entire configuration system. It would be good to point out that Configuration can read from multiple providers, including secrets, KeyVault, environment variables etc. An `appsettings.json` only accessible by the app pool/service account, is pretty safe up to a point. An environment variable to a container by eg Kubernetes is similarly safe, because only the containerized app can read it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What would be even the point of passing connection string (with or without credentials) to end-users web browser? He cannot reach database anyway. Would Blazor pack `appsettings.json` and send them to end-users browser by default? :O

Comment: @Nenad who said anything about passing the connection string to the browser? (Except the OP) The OP confused what goes where

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - OPs intention is making Blazor WASM public. So "only" OP is asking about it.

Comment: @Nenad Blazor WASM *is* public by definition. The OP confused Blazor Server, Blazor WASM, and Web API. I'd even say there's confusion on what an SPA is in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so instead of telling that OP confused the stuff, maybe clarify it for him. If he wasn't confused, he would not ask the question in the first place. And the reason he confused the stuff, is because it is confusing. Suddenly C# runs in the browser, on the server, etc... some calls are proxied to the server, some are not. Of course he is confused.

Answer (score 1):

About what `appsetting.json` are we talking about?
I guess it's `appsettings.json` on Server project while using Hosted solution for Blazor app. (otherwise it would be highly non-standard and unsecured to let your connection string be downloaded to client)

If "make it public" means people will use your webapp, but your source code of Server app is not public - You are technically kind of fine, because `appsettings.json` doesn't get to client. I would not recommend though.

Your next option can be storing your real connection string within some hosting configuration ([tutorial for azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal)). That way you can even open-sourced your code, because connection string is not there any more.

Best option is probably to store it securely in something like [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview).

Answer (score 1):

Consider everything that goes to the client as readable.
Make your decisions from there.

If you connection string contains a secret, like a password, it should not be sent to the client.